# Face values in obj file is more than vertex count

Tags: mesh, opengl

When I exported the cone.obj from Blender. I got 33 vertices. But the face values specified in the .Obj files seem to included vertex till 65. How can i device what will be the vertex coordinates for any face value from 33 to 65 ?

For example (cone.obj)

```
f 1/33/31 2/34/31 3/35/31 4/36/31 5/37/31 6/38/31 7/39/31 8/40/31 9/41/31 10/42/31 11/43/31 12/44/31 13/45/31 14/46/31 15/47/31 16/48/31 17/49/31 18/50/31 19/51/31 20/52/31 21/53/31 22/54/31 23/55/31 24/56/31 25/57/31 26/58/31 27/59/31 28/60/31 29/61/31 30/62/31 31/63/31 32/64/31
f 31/32/32 33/2/32 32/65/32
f 32/65/33 33/2/33 1/1/33
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the face information is arranged `number/number/number`.

**NOTE:**

sometimes not all three components are present, for example: `number//number`.

These components are references to a *vertex*, a *vertex texture* and a *vertex normal* in this order.
As I said earlier sometimes not all three are present.

In your example, notice that the first component in all the faces (the vertex index)
ranges from 1 to 33, as it should.

**NOTE:**

In the OBJ file the indices start from 1 and not 0.

Here is an example of how the indices work, I removed the material reference and title.

```
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000   #   <-- this is vertex index 1
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000

vt 0.875000 0.500000          #   <-- this is vertex texture index 1
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.000000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.000000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.125000 0.750000
vt 0.125000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.875000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 1.000000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000

f 5/1/1 3/2/1 1/3/1
f 3/2/2 8/4/2 4/5/2
f 7/6/3 6/7/3 8/8/3
f 2/9/4 8/10/4 6/11/4
f 1/3/5 4/5/5 2/9/5
f 5/12/6 2/9/6 6/7/6
f 5/1/1 7/13/1 3/2/1
f 3/2/2 7/14/2 8/4/2
f 7/6/3 5/12/3 6/7/3
f 2/9/4 4/5/4 8/10/4
f 1/3/5 3/2/5 4/5/5
f 5/12/6 1/3/6 2/9/6
```